# NSCollectionView visibleRect property

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, nscollectionview

The NSCollectionView displays multiple items. I have a Grid like layout.

I need to determine the items that are currently visible.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528194-visibleitems?language=objc) there is a method

```
- (NSArray<NSCollectionViewItem *> *)visibleItems;
```

with the description

> The items returned by this method represent the ones that are active and currently being managed by the collection view. This array may contain items that are outside of the collection view’s actual visible rectangle. For example, it may contain items that were recently visible but have since been scrolled out of view. To test whether an item is actually visible, check to see if its frame rectangle intersects the `visibleRect` of the collection view.

So I need to manually calculate which items are visible based on its `frame` coordinates and `visibleRect` of the collectionView. It's fine of course.

However, what bothers me is which coordinates `visibleRect` returns.

Usually and it agrees with the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html) if I have lets say

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:...];

[imageView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0., -100., 300., 400.)];
[imageView setImage:img];
NSLog(..., [imageView visibleRect]);
NSLog(..., [imageView frame]);
```

then the visible rectangle will have as expected

```
x=0
y=100
width = 300
height = 300
```

And this fully agrees with the documentation.

However, in the case of the `NSCollectionView` it behaves differently.
If I created items and the first item is displayed, then `visibleRect` will display

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

Now if I scroll a little bit down the output will be

```
x = 0
y = some number > 0
```

However, I would expect that it should return a different `y` value. Because

> A view's visible rectangle reflects the portion of the contents that are actually displayed, in terms of the view's bounds coordinate system

Assuming that there is no spacing between items and items are identical

```
x = 0
y = (numItems - 1) * itemHeight
```

[image]

This behavior is not a problem of course. I can use these values to calculate things based on the returned values. I want to understand the reason.

What am I missing?

P.S. Essentially `NSCollectionView` `visibleRect` together with `frame` of its items behaves as if the origin of the coordinate system were in the top left corner with `y` increasing down and `x` increasing right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You say 'I need to determine the items that are currently visible', but (as you point out) the NSCollectionView already does that for you.  Who is "I" in this case?  Your own subclass of NSCollectionView, or NSCollectionViewLayout?

Comment: @mr.fixit Collection view does not do this automatically. It can return only the array of items that were in use recently. However, if the user scrolls away an item it can still be in use, but is not really visible. In order to determine the actually visible items you need to check if the frame rectangle of the item intersects the visible rectangle of the collection view. When you start doing it you need to deal with coordinates. Since, in the documentation it is not written that NSCollectionView is using flipped coordinates I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCollectionView` uses a flipped coordinate system.
See the [flipped](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483532-flipped?language=occ) property of `NSView` and [Flipped Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-SW16).